# How to hide .htaccess redirect from user

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdirectory, subdomain

I have server with domain www.domain.com and multiple sub domains sub1.domain.com, sub2.domain.com. They are all pointing to server root.

I'd like users to access specific folders by subdomains. For example:

- sub1.domain.com/someURI => sub1.domain.com/subFolder1/someURI
- sub2.domain.com/someURI => sub1.domain.com/subFolder2/someURI

I would like to **hide these redirections** from users. I tried following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub1.domain.com/subFolder1/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub2.domain.com/subFolder2/$1 [R,L]
```

It is redirecting correctly only without any URI and redirection is visible.

Comment: Is there any reason that keeps you from creating two different VirtualHosts pointing to the required directories?

Comment: _“and redirection is visible”_ – go look up what the `R` flag stands for.

Comment: @CBroe I know that R stands for redirect. I found some information that R without parameter is equal to R=302 - temporary move and it should be hidden from user.

Comment: @Eineki I'ts hosted server and I do not have required permissions

Comment: the R flag force an external redirect, you need an internal one (without a roundtrip to the browser). Maybe you should just omit that flag...

Comment: _“ found some information that R without parameter is equal to R=302 - temporary move and it should be hidden from user”_ – well, you found wrong. Whether the status code is 301 or 302 only affects how the client treats the redirect – as permanent, or temporary. But that doesn’t change the fact that both are external redirects, and therefor the target URL shows up in the browser address bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issues that are causing external redirect:

1. Using `R` flag in `RewriteRule`
2. Using Absolute URL starting with `http://` in target
3. Another issue is that your rewrite rule is unconditional which can cause infinite looping.

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =sub1.domain.com
RewriteRule ^((?!subFolder1/).*)$ subFolder1/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =sub2.domain.com
RewriteRule ^((?!subFolder2/).*)$ subFolder2/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: It's working like a charm. Thank you! Could you explain the RewriteRule because I'm not sure if I got it?

Comment: `RewriteRule` is pretty much same with one addition of negative lookahead i.e. `(?!subFolder1/)` which means don't forward is request is already starting from `/subFolder2/`